# How to extract values from complex XML in R without discarding nodes without existing value?

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I am starting with a large, complex XML-file and need to extract values and attributes of certain sub(sub...)nodes. But because not all subnodes have all wanted values (some are missing) I cannot easily use the very fast `xml_find_all` (xml2 package), because it will of course not include the subnodes with missing values.

My solution is to use a for-loop cycling through all of my xml-nodes (Objects) and check within each node, if my desired value is exists - if yes, extract it. Thanks to the index of the loop I know to which Object it belongs and write it to the corresponding `data.frame$Feature[i]`.

This approach works fine, but for my large XML-Node it takes a **VERY long time (20 min) and is very memory consuming** (~1.5GB, because of if-loop).
My XML: 100MB, about 30.000 "entries/Objects" each with about 50 features (~ 2 Mio lines)

The main problem which I figured out: `xpathSApply(...xml_path(Obj[i]...)` is very slow, if the indexing [i] of my loop is quite high (>5000)

**My questions are:**

- Is there any better/simpler ideas to solve my problem with a very
  complex and higly inhomogenic, structured XML, where not all features
  are present in all object(nodes)?
- I read [this interesting approach](https://hopstat.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/faster-xml-conversion-to-data-frames/), but could not figure out how to translate it to my very complex XML, where my desired values are
  in different Nodeset-levels...
- Is there maybe some nested xpathSApply-expression to circumvent a for-loop and avoid using index?
- Do you now any "vector"-processing approaches (which are quite faster in R) for my problem?

See my MWE-Code with some more comments below.

**XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<featureMember>
        <Object>
                <XML_Name>Object 1</XML_Name>
               <XML_Feature1>
                   <XML_Feature1a href="URL1"></XML_Feature1a>
                </XML_Feature1>
                <XML_Feature2>
                   <XML_Feature2a>1</XML_Feature2a>
                   <XML_Feature2a>1x</XML_Feature2a>
                   <XML_Feature2a>1y</XML_Feature2a>
                </XML_Feature2>
                <XML_Feature3>
                   <XML_Feature3a>F3a_1</XML_Feature2a>
                   <XML_Feature3b>F3b_1</XML_Feature2a>
                </XML_Feature3>
                <XML_Feature3>
                   <XML_Feature3a>F3a_2</XML_Feature2a>
                   <XML_Feature3b>F3b_2</XML_Feature2a>
                </XML_Feature3>
                <XML_Feature4>F4_1</XML_Feature4>
                <XML_Feature4>F4_2</XML_Feature4>   
        </Object>       
        <Object >
            <XML_Name>Object 2</XML_Name>
               <XML_Feature1>
                   <XML_Feature1a href="URL2"></XML_Feature1a>
                </XML_Feature1>         
        </Object>       
        <Object >
        <XML_Name>Object 3</XML_Name>
            <XML_Feature1>
               <XML_Feature1>               
               </XML_Feature1>
            </XML_Feature1>
            <XML_Feature2>
                <XML_Feature2a>Value 3</XML_Feature2a>
            </XML_Feature2>
        </Object>
</featureMember>
```

**R**

```r
require(xml2)
require(XML)
test_xml2 <- read_xml("above_file.xml") # using Packet xml2 (for using xml_find_all)
test_XML <- xmlParse("above_file.xml") # Packet XML (for using xpathSApply)

  # XML-Noteset of all Objects I want to process:
Obj <- xml_find_all(test_xml2, "//Object") # --> has 3 nodes, contains all Objects!
  
  # initialize a destination dataframe and fill with NAs
df <- data.frame('Name'=integer(), 'f2a'=character() , 'f1a'=character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df[1:length(Obj),] <- NA

# My Initial approach to extract all features by xml_find_all (which is very fast) is not working because not all xml-nodes have all wanted xml-features:
Name <- xml_text(xml_find_all(test_xml2, "//XML_Name")) 
  # --> length(Name)=3, because all 3 Objects have a name!
f1a  <- xml_attr(xml_find_all(test_xml2, "//XML_Feature1/XML_Feature1a"),"href") 
  # --> length(f1a)=2, because XML_Feature1a is missing in Object3! 
f2a  <- xml_text(xml_find_all(test_xml2, "//XML_Feature2/XML_Feature2a")) 
  # --> length(f2a)=2, because XML_Feature2a is missing in Object2!
# Joining these to a final df is not possible, because "Name", "f2a" and "f1a" have of course different lengths, plus correct data matching is not possible!


# Therefore I decided to make instead the following approach.
  # 1.) crawl all features, which are present in all nodes, because its fast (here: "Name"):
df$Name <- xml_text(xml_find_all(test_xml2, "//XML_Name"))
  
  # 2.) making a for-loop over all Objects/XML-Nodes of interest and check if eacht wanted feature exist.
    # if yes: write to df$FeatureXY[i]
    # if not: make nothing (thus df$FeatureXY[i]stays NA from initialization)
for (i in 1:length(Obj))
{  # 1. Feature:
 tmp  <- xpathSApply(test_XML, paste0(xml_path(Obj[i]),"/XML_Feature1/XML_Feature1a"),  xmlGetAttr, "href")
 if(length(tmp )>0) { df$f1a[i] <- tmp # otherwise it would produce an error-message}
    # 2. Feature:
 tmp  <- xpathSApply(test_XML, paste0(xml_path(Obj[i]),"/XML_Feature2/XML_Feature2a"),  xmlValue)
 if(length(tmp )>0) { df$f2a[i] <- tmp} 
}  

# Result of df as it should be:
# Name      f2a             f1a   f3a            f3b             f4
# Object 1  1 # 1x # 1y     URL1  F3a_1 # F3a_2  F3b_1 # F3b_2   F4_1 # F4_2
# Object 2  NA              URL2  NA             NA              NA 
# Object 3  Value 3         NA    NA             NA              NA
```

*Edit 1:* Extended XML example (multiple elements of feature2a, feature3a/b feature4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems like this can be tricky, in order to handle any potential changes between the sample data and the actual data.  If we assume there is at most a single "Feature1a" node and at most a single "Feature2a" node per "Object" then this breaks down to a straight forward problem.

First find all of the parent "Object" nodes then using this vector of nodes parse each one for the Name, feature1a attribute and feature2a text.  `xml_find_first` will return a value if the node exists, if not then it will return NA. Since the `xml_find_first` function is vectorized, it will operate on the vector of parent nodes without the need of a loop and with a very significant performance improvement.

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

#Read file to process
doc<- read_xml("above_file.xml")

#find parent nodes
parents <- xml_find_all(doc, ".//Object")

#Now extract the requested data from each parent
# Notice the use of the . in the xpath. 
# //  finds anywhere in the document (ignoring the current node)
# .// finds anywhere beneath the current node
Names<- xml_find_first(parents, ".//XML_Name") %>% xml_text()
feature1 <- xml_find_first(parents, ".//XML_Feature1a") %>% xml_attr("href")

#fill features with first elements as default
feature2 <- xml_find_first(parents, ".//XML_Feature2a") %>% xml_text()
#find parents with more than 1 feature2
moretwos<-which(xml_find_all(parents, ".//XML_Feature2")  %>% xml_length() >1)
#reparse the parent nodes with more than one child
feature2[moretwos] <-sapply(parents[moretwos], function(node){
        xml_find_all(node, ".//XML_Feature2a") %>% xml_text() %>% paste(collapse = "#")
})


#Make combinded dataframe
answer <-data.frame(Names, feature1, feature2)
answer
```

Here is a similar question but with an unknown number of subnodes: [Create data frame from xml with different number of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60622303/create-data-frame-from-xml-with-different-number-of-elements/60623391#60623391)

**UPDATE**
 For your revised problem of having multiple subnodes with multiple children, but no grandchildren here is option.

```
#find parent nodes
parents<-xml_find_all(doc, ".//Object")

dfs<-lapply(parents, function(parent) {
  #Get oject name
  object<-xml_find_first(parent, ".//XML_Name") %>% xml_text()

  #find the number of children under each child
  numchild<-xml_children(parent) %>% xml_length()

  #if number of children is zero get name and value
  name  <- xml_children(parent)[numchild==0] %>% xml_name()
  value <- xml_children(parent)[numchild==0] %>% xml_text()

   #if the number of childern is 1 or more the get the name value of the child
   namec2  <- xml_children(parent)[numchild>=1] %>% xml_children() %>% xml_name()
   valuec2 <- xml_children(parent)[numchild>=1] %>% xml_children() %>% xml_text()

  #make data frame of the values and column headings
  df<-data.frame(object, name=c(name, namec2), value=c(value, valuec2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  print(df)
  df
})

#Make combinded dataframe
answer<-bind_rows(dfs)
answer
library(tidyr) 
pivot_wider(answer, object, names_from = name, values_from= value, values_fn = list(value = toString))
```

The final answer will need to some cleaning of the columns, `gsub(", ", " # ", ...)` and retrieving the URL attribute from above

Comment: Your simple solution looks promising for me. Only problem: some of the features could occure multiple times in one "parent" and I want to coerc it to one entry. Inside my loop I used `paste(xpathSApply(...),collapse="#")`. Any idea how to achive this here? Repacing `xml_find_first` with `xml_find_all` doesn't work, bacause the "NA's" aren't preserved and collapsing to one entry does not work that simple...  Here the edited XML of "Object 1":
`<XML_Feature2>
<XML_Feature2a>Value 1</XML_Feature2a>  <XML_Feature2a>Value 1x</XML_Feature2a><XML_Feature2a>Value 1y</XML_Feature2a>
</XML_Feature2>`

Comment: Thanks to [here](https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues/237#issuecomment-430736592) I found a (nonoptimal!) solution for multiple occurences:
`feature2 = parents %>% purrr::map(~ xml_find_all(.x, ".//XML_Feature2a") %>% xml_text() %>% paste(collapse=" # ")) %>% unlist()` (I added inside bracket `paste()` and outside bracked `unlist()`)
Result: `[1] "Value 1 # Value 1b # Value 1c" [2] "" [3] "Value 3"`.
**Non-optimal part is**: a) it takes **5 mins** for my big XML (worse than inside a for-loop) b) feature2[2] should be NA instead of "" (empty). Any suggestion @Dave2e ?

Comment: @therob, see edits above. I have added a work around, but how efficient this works will completely depend on the breakdown of the missing to single to multiple nodes.  If every sub node is different, then see the link above for a more general approach, but then that is looping through all of the parent nodes.  Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for your helpful reply. I will check this next working week, if this is running well. If not I now stay with only the multiple elements (only a vew) within the loop all other with your method without loop! 

All in all I already have now a much faster (5-7min instead of 15-25min) and less memory eating script (1 vs. 2.5GB RAM) thanks to you. I will mark your answer as "solution" - maybe I will come back next week again. Cheers and thanks!

Comment: your solution for multiple entries works indeed with the XML-code snippet of the comment above @Dave2e - thanks! Unfortunately in my real XML I found **slightly different versions**, which I introduced in the initial XML example as new Features 3a/b and 4 - for all I cold not really figure out how to modify your working approach of feature2 (gathering `moretwos` morethreeas/morefours as the main part). Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At 100 MB, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files such as very nested levels to flatter outputs for easy R data frame import. R can run XSLT with `xslt`, extended package to `xml2`. Otherwise use *any* [XSLT executable](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) to handle the transformation as demonstrated further below. And because you also use `XML`, consider its convenience method `xmlToDataFrame` for import of flatter XML files.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/featureMember">
      <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Object"/>
      </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Object">
      <data>
        <Name><xsl:apply-templates select="XML_Name"/></Name>
        <f1><xsl:apply-templates select="XML_Feature1/XML_Feature1a/@href"/></f1>
        <f2><xsl:apply-templates select="XML_Feature2"/></f2>
      </data>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## <kbd>[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MvmXiE)</kbd>

**XML** Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<root>
  <data>
    <Name>Object 1</Name>
    <f1>URL1</f1>
    <f2>Value 1</f2>
  </data>
  <data>
    <Name>Object 2</Name>
    <f1>URL2</f1>
    <f2 />
  </data>
  <data>
    <Name>Object 3</Name>
    <f1 />
    <f2>Value 3</f2>
  </data>
</root>
```

**R** *(no `for` loops, `apply` calls, `if` logic, or XPath search needed)*

```
library(xml2)
library(xslt)
library(XML)

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc <- read_xml('/path/toInput.xml')
style <- read_xml('/path/to/Script.xsl', package = "xslt")

# TRANSFORM NESTED INPUT INTO FLATTER OUTPUT
new_xml <- as.character(xslt::xml_xslt(doc, style))

# PARSE FLATTER XML
flat_xml <- XML::xmlParse(new_xml, asText=TRUE)

# BUILD DATA FRAME
final_df <- XML::xmlToDataFrame(flat_xml, XML::getNodes(nodes="//data"))
```

To demonstrate an external XSLT solution, below interfaces to the [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html) command line tool available for installation on Unix machines (i.e., Linux, MacOS):

```
library(XML)

# COMMAND LINE CALL TO UNIX'S XSLTPROC (ALTERNATIVE TO xslt PACKAGE)
system("xsltproc -o /path/to/input.xml /path/to/script.xsl /path/to/output.xml")

flat_xml <- xmlParse("/path/to/output.xml")

final_df <- xmlToDataFrame(flat_xml, getNodes(nodes="//data"))
```